# Using AssocQueryString to get 64-bit application command from 32-bit application, but not working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit

I try to use AssocQueryString to get association information, myapp.exe is 32-bit executable file. Here's my code.

```
WCHAR commandline[_MAX_PATH];
DWORD size = _MAX_PATH;
HRESULT h = AssocQueryStringW(ASSOCF_OPEN_BYEXENAME, ASSOCSTR_COMMAND, execName, 0, commandline, &size);
if (SUCCEEDED(h)) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

I find that if "execName" is a 32-bit application, this api works perfect.
For example,

```
WCHAR *execName = L"mspaint.exe";
```

We can get command = "C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe" "%1"

But if giving a 64-bit application(ex: PaintDotNet.exe), SUCCEEDED(h) would return FALSE.
Variable h = 0x80070483, which means "no application is associated with the file extension".

Since above observation, I guess this api may fail when trying to get 64-bit application information.

So my question are:

1. Is there anything I ignore or wrong usage of AssocQueryString?
2. Is there another way to get a 64-bit app info from a 32-bit app?

By the way, I don't want to just compile my app as a 64-bit app.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: This function retrieves the info from the registry.  You are having a fight with the [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, @HansPassant. I try to use AssocQueryString but this function still fail. Finally, I simply use RegQueryValue and KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag to get what I want. Thanks a lot for your information!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Is there anything I ignore or wrong usage of AssocQueryString?**

1) ASSOCSTR_COMMAND replace to ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE

and you can get just "C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe"

2) SUCCEEDED is non-negative numbers indicate true

(((HRESULT)(hr)) >= 0)

so if you check success, check result equal zero

**2. Is there another way to get a 64-bit app info from a 32-bit app?**

1) if your windows x64, folder C:\Windows\system32\ is for 64bit files.

cf>http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm
C:\Windows\System32 Windows System folder (system directory) for 64-bit files
C:\Windows\SysWOW64 Windows System folder (system directory) for 32-bit files

2) just check result equal zero, and print it.
do not use SUCCEEDED(h) in this case.

AssocQueryString's return value S_OK(0), E_POINTER, S_FALSE(1)